# Trying to root my kindle fire hd but no "Enable ADB " button

Tags: root, kindle-fire, kindle

I have checked everywhere for people having the same problem and I havent found any. The "enable adb" button is not in the security menu. Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Comment: Which generation Kindle Fire is this? On the ICS based Fire's it is there (below Device Administrators), and on the Gingerbread ones I think it's effectively enabled by default. Is the problem that you don't have the drivers on the PC side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had the 1st gen kindle. It has ADB enabled by default.